# VBA Runtime Error 1004 “Application-defined or Object-defined error” when pasting value into a cell in another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I can't figure out why I am getting this error. I have not been able to find anybody with similar code getting this error.

The main objective is to run this from the starting workbook, jump to the destination workbook to get 3 addresses of cells, then jump back to the starting workbook and paste a formula referencing those cells in the destination workbook.

I thought getting the formula right would be the hard part. But everything works except It is not allowing me to paste the final formula string into the cells. Giving me Runtime Error 1004 “Application-defined or Object-defined error”. What am I missing here?

```
Sub DefeatRunTimeError()

'Starting Workbook
Dim startWB As Workbook
Dim GENTemplate As Worksheet
'Destination Workbook
Dim destWB As Workbook
Dim destBackgroundFormulas As Worksheet
'Other Variables
Dim TabName As String
Dim bLoc As Range
Dim bTSD As Range
Dim bTGL As Range
Dim bRU As Range
'Set Starting Workbook
TabName = ActiveSheet.Name
Set startWB = ActiveWorkbook
Set GENTemplate = startWB.Sheets(TabName)

'Define Filename of Destination Workbook
MasterLoc = startWB.Names("MasterProjectTrackerLocation").RefersToRange.Value

    'Open Destination Workbook
            Workbooks.Open (MasterLoc)

    'Set Destination Workbook
        Set destWB = ActiveWorkbook
        Set destBackgroundFormulas = destWB.Worksheets("Background Formulas")

    'Define ranges
        destBackgroundFormulas.Activate
        Set bLoc = destBackgroundFormulas.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        bLoc.Value = TabName
        Set bTSD = bLoc.Offset(0, 1)
        Set bTGL = bLoc.Offset(0, 2)
        Set bRU = bLoc.Offset(0, 3)

    'Write Formula referencing these cells
        strfile = Replace(ThisWorkbook.FullName, ThisWorkbook.Name, "[" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "]")
        thefilename = "='" & strfile & "Background Formulas" & "'!"
        TargetStartDate = thefilename & bTSD.Address
        TargetGoLive = thefilename & bTGL.Address
        ReviewUpdate = thefilename & bRU.Address

    'Paste Formulas into Original Workbook
        Set bTSD = GENTemplate.Range("b12")
        Set bTGL = GENTemplate.Range("b13")
        Set bRU = GENTemplate.Range("a4")
    'ERROR GIVEN ON THE LINE BELOW RUNTIME 1004
        bTSD.Value = TargetStartDate
        bTGL.Value = TargetGoLive
        bRU.Value = ReviewUpdate

 End Sub
```

Edited Version

```
Sub DefeatRunTimeError()

'Starting Workbook
Dim startWB As Workbook
Dim GENTemplate As Worksheet
'Destination Workbook
Dim destWB As Workbook
Dim destBackgroundFormulas As Worksheet
'Other Variables
Dim TabName As String
Dim bLoc As Range
Dim bTSD As Range
Dim bTGL As Range
Dim bRU As Range
'Set Starting Workbook
TabName = ActiveSheet.Name
Set startWB = ActiveWorkbook
Set GENTemplate = startWB.Sheets(TabName)

'Define Filename of Destination Workbook
MasterLoc = startWB.Names("MasterProjectTrackerLocation").RefersToRange.Value

    'Open Destination Workbook
        Workbooks.Open (MasterLoc)

    'Set Destination Workbook
        Set destWB = Application.Workbooks.Open(MasterLoc)
        Set destBackgroundFormulas = destWB.Worksheets("Background Formulas")


    'Define ranges
        destBackgroundFormulas.Activate
        strfile = Replace(destWB.FullName, destWB.Name, "[" & destWB.Name & "]")
        thefilename = "='" & strfile & "Background Formulas" & "'!"

        Set bLoc = destBackgroundFormulas.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        bLoc.Value = TabName
        Set bTSD = bLoc.Offset(0, 1)
        Set bTGL = bLoc.Offset(0, 2)
        Set bRU = bLoc.Offset(0, 3)

    'Write Formula referencing these cells

        TargetStartDate = thefilename & bTSD.Address
        TargetGoLive = thefilename & bTGL.Address
        ReviewUpdate = thefilename & bRU.Address

    'Paste Formulas into Original Workbook
        Set bTSD = GENTemplate.Range("b12")
        Set bTGL = GENTemplate.Range("b13")
        Set bRU = GENTemplate.Range("a4")

        'MsgBox (TargetStartDate)

        bTSD.Formula = TargetStartDate
        bTGL.Formula = TargetGoLive
        bRU.Formula = ReviewUpdate

 End Sub
```

Returns   : TargetStartDate : "='Z:\Master Projects[Master Projects.xlsm]Background Formulas'!$B$16" : Variant/String

For TargetStartDate, which yields the correct formula.

Comment: Why would you open the workbook, then set `destWB` to the `ActiveWorkbook`. Try to avoid using __any__ method with the work _Active_ in it, unless you truly need it. `Set destWB = Application.Workbooks.Open(MasterLoc)`

Comment: And what is this line for: `Set startSht = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(TabName)`? Why do you use explicit workbook objects on the 3 lines above then use the `ActiveWorkbook` for this? Set your workbook obj as you've done with the others. And `startWB` should be explicit as well. Is this code in the `startWB`? If so, instead of using `ActiveWorkbook`, use `ThisWorkbook`.

Comment: What is the value of `TargetStartDate` when it errors?

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I am still learning how to make my macros less clunky and your tips help a lot. As for the startsht lines, I removed those just now in an edit. This is a snip from a larger macro that is about 2000 lines long, I thought I removed all the other working lines to prevent confusion.

Comment: Unrelated to your issue, but setting the `bTSD.value` will just plunk down the string literal that `TargetStartDate` variable holds into that `bTSD` cell. Instead you want to set that cell's formula. `bTSD.Formula = TargetStartDate`  That probably won't fix your current issue, but will solve the next one.

Comment: I'm also very curious what the value and type of `TargetStartDate` is when this errors. When you hit `debug` go to `View>>Locals Window` and copy/paste what the value of that variable is here (and make note of the variable type... I'm assuming `variant/string` at this point in the processing).

Comment: @JNevill    : TargetStartDate : "='Z:\Master Projects\Template\Concept Testing\[Concept Testing - Project Tracker v1.0.xlsm]Background Formulas'!$B$15" : Variant/String

Should say something like
"='[Master Projects.xlsm]Background Formulas'!$B$15"

Comment: @JNevill you were right about it being a **variant/string** do you have any ideas of why that is giving me this error?

Comment: I closed and reopened my spreadsheet and the .formula tip fixed the error. Thank you!